# how to deal with dynamic ip address mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, ip-address

I am working on asp.net mvc 4 web application wherein i have functionality to upload files to a machine connected in LAN (network). This works fine. Also i have functionality to download the files to local machine that are being uploaded on file server machine. For this, i have created a website and virtual directory on IIS on file server machine and given its path in web.config file as-

```
<appSettings>
<add key ="DownloadUrl" value="http://192.168.1.9:85/" />
</appSettings>
```

but whenever, the machine is restarted or internet connection is restarted, the ip address changes and i have to update it in web.config file always. Is there any permanent solution for this?

I hope you get my question. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use a hostname or DNS name instead of IP address?

Comment: how can I can use it? I have no idea.

Comment: I mean, you can set the DownloadUrl to http://yourhostname:85. If it's intranet, you can use the computer name.

Comment: But i have it on IIS. so will i be able to use that way?

Comment: If what I understood is correct, you will access the url in your IIS web site. It's just an address so if the server where IIS locates can access the computer(you can ping), it's OK to use hostname instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have also problems with changing IP addresses at some of my offices and I use DynDNS to get around it. I just replace the IP address with the dynamic address. Works like a charm!

Comment: how do you use it? can you give me example

Comment: You register on a web site that can support you with a dynamic dns. On http://www.noip.com/free/ you can do it for free. I personally use http://www.dyndns.com/dns/ but that service will cost you a few bucks every year.

Comment: Basically it works like this. You get a domain name instead of your ip address, like `myoffice.dyndns.org` that updates everytime your ip changes. You can then use `myoffice.dyndns.org` instead of the ip address in your settings.

Comment: You also need to either (1) Update your firewall to report new IP to the dynamic dns service or (2) Install a program supplied by the dynamic dns service that makes the update for you (in case your firewall can't do this)

Comment: but i don't need to get any domain name or so. I think you are not getting my question. The computer from where I need to download the file will be in my office itself, connected in network!

Comment: Ah, ok...then I would suggest giving the computer a static IP or, if you have access to DHCP settings, to lock the IP of that computer so it always gets the same IP.